# Nuxt emit data undefined

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to emit from child to parent with a payload and i get undefined value

What i'm doing, click on child button:

```
nextStep () {
  this.$emit('next', { guests: this.guests, date: this.date })
}
```

Parent:

```
<BookStepTwo v-if="step === 2" :date="date" :guests="guests" @next="handleStepTwoNext()" @back="step = 1" />

  methods: {
    handleStepTwoNext (data) {
      console.log(data)
      this.step = 3
    }
  }
Payload: [{"guests":"1","date":{"start":"2021-07-21","end":"2021-07-22"}}]
```

Data gives me undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use arrow `()` in the emitted event handler :

```
 @next="handleStepTwoNext"
```